# Dropdown doesn't take SelectedValue

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, ado.net

I have a weird problem. I fill dropdown whith this code

```
   MySqlCommand cmdAreaPassive = new MySqlCommand();
    cmdAreaPassive.CommandText = "Select BolgeID, BolgeAdi, AktiPasif ";
    cmdAreaPassive.CommandText += "From tbl_bolgeler ";
    cmdAreaPassive.CommandText += "Where AktiPasif = 1 ";
    cmdAreaPassive.CommandText += "Order By BolgeAdi ASC ";
    cmdAreaPassive.Connection = con;

    MySqlDataAdapter drAreaPassive = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdAreaPassive);
    DataSet dsAreaPassive = new DataSet();
    drAreaPassive.Fill(dsAreaPassive);

    ddlAreaDelete.DataSource = dsAreaPassive;
    ddlAreaDelete.DataTextField = "BolgeAdi";
    ddlAreaDelete.DataValueField = "BolgeID";
    ddlAreaDelete.DataBind();

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

And i try to delete item with this code

```
        MySqlCommand cmdDelete = new MySqlCommand();
        cmdDelete.CommandText = "Update tbl_bolgeler ";
        cmdDelete.CommandText += "Set AktiPasif = @AktiPasif ";
        cmdDelete.CommandText += "Where BolgeID = @BolgeID ";
        cmdDelete.Connection = con;

        cmdDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BolgeID", ddlAreaDelete.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmdDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AktiPasif", "0");

        cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

everything is normal until to select object. It has to take selected value but it takes selected index. I try SelectedItem.Value and SelectedValue but both of them doesn't work. Sorry for my bad english, thanks.

Comment: I don't see any dropdown filling logic

Comment: could show your dropdown fill code !!!!

Comment: Sorry i posted wrong code blog, now i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I think, i solved the problem

My code was like that

```
  cmdDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BolgeID", ddlAreaDelete.SelectedItem.Value);
```

and i chanced like that

```
        int selectedIndex = ddlAreaDelete.SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex >= 0)
        {
         cmdDelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BolgeID",ddlAreaDelete.Items[selectedIndex].Value);
        }
```

but i still don't know what was the reason